# Avearge Partial Effects for discrete variables

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, multinomial-distribution, logit, marginal-effect

I have individual specific variables that are both categorical and numeric, i have calculated the marginal effects for continuous variables where the mean is used, how do i calculate the Average Partial Effects for the categorical variables in R. I have used `mlogit` package. Thank you!

Comment: Calculate the difference in probability between x1=y and x1=z, for all n observations. The average out, you know have the APE

Comment: @Repmat can you please post probably an abstract code snippet for APE,  thank you